# Excel 2007. Write changes back to extern file source

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

it's possible to import data into an excel sheet from an external (csv) file.

Every time content of this external file will be changed, we'll see these changes in the excel sheet.

But is it possible to save changes automatically to the extern file source back if the user changed data in the excel sheet?

> Why are users importing data? They can just open the csv in excel and
>   it will remain updated.

Why so "complicated"?

We have already all our data in Excel. We are doing some manipulations with formulas and so on. I think, it's not possible to save formulas in csv-format.

But we also using SVN. Since it's not that easy to merge Excel-Files in SVN it was our idea to separate data representation and data source.

At the same time we want to change data in excel and in csv.

Comment: Why are users importing data? They can just open the csv in excel and it will remain updated.

Comment: @Raystafarian I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

You could write a macro, but it would not be automatic.

Your best bet would likely be to make the excel file read only so that people realize they need to update the original data source.

Comment: Hmmmm ... ok, I'll try to find the macro-way, because your second suggestion is unfortunately not the option for us